# Hover event CSS not working at all

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div appear over an image using CSS "hover" event. But it's not working at all. Nothing happens at all... could you check what's going on?
Thank you.

```
.over {

        display: none;
        opacity: 0.6;
        background: #F58634;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 171px;
        height: 114px;
        z-index: 2;

    }

    .over:hover {

        display: block;

    }

    .img {

        z-index: 1;

    }
```

And here is the HTML...

```
<td width="171px" >
                <img class="img" src="./img/cat/_MG_7415.JPG" alt="" width="171px" height="114px">

                <div class="over">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>PESO</td>
                            <td>0,500gr</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>VALIDADE</td>
                            <td>60 DIAS<br><span style="font-size:5px;">APÓS DATA DE FABRICAÇÃO</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CAIXA</td>
                            <td>5kg</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TEMPERATURA</td>
                            <td>0 a 5ºC</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </td>
```

So, I want the div class ".over" to overlay ".img" to show some information mouse is on the image. Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: Yes. Does it affect?

Comment: `display:none` doesn't display the element, so you can't hover over it. Use `visibility` instead

Comment: Ah, I see... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.over {
        display:none;
        opacity: 0.6;
        background: #F58634;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 171px;
        height: 114px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    img.img:hover + .over {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<td width="171px" >
                <img class="img" src="./img/cat/_MG_7415.JPG" alt="" width="171px" height="114px">

                <div class="over">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>PESO</td>
                            <td>0,500gr</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>VALIDADE</td>
                            <td>60 DIAS<br><span style="font-size:5px;">APÓS DATA DE FABRICAÇÃO</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CAIXA</td>
                            <td>5kg</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>TEMPERATURA</td>
                            <td>0 a 5ºC</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </td>
```

CSS solution: Use `+` selector to select the `next` element.

```
.over {
    display:none;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: #F58634;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 171px;
    height: 114px;
    z-index: 2;
}
img.img:hover + .over {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('img.img').hover(function() {
            $('div.over').show();
        }, function() {
            $('div.over').hide();
        });
    );
</script>
```

In this case you will no longer need this:

```
.over:hover {

    display: block;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The div has display:none so it's not being displayed and it is therefore impossible to hover over it.

Try changing it to display:block and instead changing the opacity in the hover.

As mentioned by [Jacob Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3285730/jacob-gray) in a comment to your post, you can use visibility.
So, instead of changing the opacity in the hover, you can set that once and then set visibility initially to hidden and then to visible during the hover.

Comment: I thought the same thing. But the OP wants to display the `.over` on hovering on the previous image. Not the `.over` itself.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/52mmdxyb/

Dear,
You have defined hover event on `.over` whereas it's already hidden. When it's not available, how we can mouse over on that element!
What you need is that hover on image then show the content in the div.
I have done accordingly. Please check [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/52mmdxyb/)

Removed:

```
.over:hover {

        display: block;

    }
```

And changed it to

```
.img:hover +  .over {
        display: block;
    }
```

it means: if mouse over on image, please show content of `div` having class `over`